# How to Split group of columns in a single row to multiple rows in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a row comprised of 3 different phone number types (HOME, OFFICE, MOBILE) and each phone type has 3 columns (CC, NUM, EXT). Here is a row in my table:

```
DATEMODIFIED,HOME_PHONE_CC,HOME_PHONE_NUM,HOME_PHONE_EXT,OFFICE_PHONE_CC,OFFICE_PHONE_NUM,OFFICE_PHONE_EXT,MOBILE_PHONE_CC,MOBILE_PHONE_NUM,MOBILE_PHONE_EXT
2019-05-17,1,123-456-789,111,1,456-789-123,222,1,789-123-456,333
```

I want to convert it into 3 rows to get each row per phone type

```
DATEMODIFIED,PHONE_CC,PHONE_NUM,PHONE_EXT
2019-05-17,1,123-456-789,111
2019-05-17,1,456-789-123,222
2019-05-17,1,789-123-456,333
```

To split into multiple rows, I could use UNION by querying it 3 times for each phone type.

```
Select datemodified, HOME_PHONE_CC, HOME_PHONE_NUM, HOME_PHONE_EXT from table
UNION
Select datemodified, OFFICE_PHONE_CC, OFFICE_PHONE_NUM, OFFICE_PHONE_EXT from table
UNION
Select datemodified, MOBILE_PHONE_CC, MOBILE_PHONE_NUM, MOBILE_PHONE_EXT from table
```

But I want to check if there is another better way in Snowflake to do this?

Answer (score 1):

a simple improvement would be to use UNION ALL instead of UNION if your three different numbers are not duplicates, to avoid the cost of deduplication:

```
with your_table(DATEMODIFIED,
              HOME_PHONE_CC, HOME_PHONE_NUM,HOME_PHONE_EXT, 
              OFFICE_PHONE_CC, OFFICE_PHONE_NUM, OFFICE_PHONE_EXT, 
              MOBILE_PHONE_CC, MOBILE_PHONE_NUM, MOBILE_PHONE_EXT) as (
    select * from values
    ('2019-05-17'::date, 1,'123-456-789',111, 1,'456-789-123',222, 1,'789-123-456',333),
    ('2020-05-17'::date, 2,'223-456-789',211, 2,'556-789-123',322, 2,'889-123-456',433)
)

Select datemodified, HOME_PHONE_CC, HOME_PHONE_NUM, HOME_PHONE_EXT from your_table
UNION ALL
Select datemodified, OFFICE_PHONE_CC, OFFICE_PHONE_NUM, OFFICE_PHONE_EXT from your_table
UNION ALL
Select datemodified, MOBILE_PHONE_CC, MOBILE_PHONE_NUM, MOBILE_PHONE_EXT from your_table
```

over really big data sets, this will save some time. if you have null values, I  would exclude them in the 3 select.